# Linux Hosting & .NET Core Docker : PlatformNotSupportedException: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is not supported on this platform

Tags: docker, active-directory, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.0, basic-authentication

I have web api implemented in .NET Core 2.0 with Basic Auth & Active Directory implemented. we are using docker for deployment. Following code I've written for Active Directory Authentication:

```
 using (PrincipalContext pContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xyz"))
            {
                try
                {
                    // validate the credentials
                    bool isValid = pContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing);

                    if (!isValid)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

To use PrincipalContext, I've added reference of

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

This is completely working on Windows machine. With Docker container also its working properly in Windows environment. But our production  server is Linux based and its not working on Linux hosting system. It shows error like

> PlatformNotSupportedException: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is not supported on this platform.

What can be done to make it working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The namespace (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement) is not supported when we use docker container to host our application. But we can do the similar setup to validate user credentials on Active Directory with this nuget package https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard and its working with docker container hosting.

```
// using Novell.Directory.Ldap;

try
{
    using (var connection = new LdapConnection())
    {
        connection.Connect("DomainUrl", 389);
        connection.Bind("username@domain", "password");
        if (connection.Bound)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
catch (LdapException ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Automatically I don't think you can do because there as the exception says the active directory API is not available in Linux. A work around is to build a windows Docker container or a windows service

Comment: Can we host Windows container on Linux server? I am new to Docker stuff. So not having detail knowledge

Comment: I don't think you can run windows container on Linux server. You will need a VM.